# ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, tkinter

Почему получаю ошибку неправильный тип данных? Сообщает, что в get возвращается тип str? Но почему, все же указано как надо...или нет?

Вот сам код: https://pastebin.com/1kRckN8y

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
def setwindow(root):
    root.title('Окно программы')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    w = 800
    h = 600
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    wh = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = int(ws / 2 - w / 2)
    y = int(wh / 2 - h / 2)
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}".format(w, h, x, y))

def equation():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global result
    x1 = str(float(b.get() * -1) + float(sqrt(b.get() ** 2 - float(a.get() * c.get() * 4) / float(a.get() * 2))))
    x2 = str(float(b.get() * -1) - float(sqrt(b.get() ** 2 - float(a.get() * c.get() * 4) / float(a.get() * 2))))
    result.config(text="x1 = " + x1 + "; " + "x2 = " + x2)

root = Tk()
setwindow(root)

label_main = Label(root, text='ax^2 + bx + c = 0', font='tahoma 20')
a = Entry(root, font='Tahoma 16')
c = Entry(root, font='Tahoma 16')
result = Label(root, font='Tahoma 18')
but = Button(root, text='Вычеслить корень уравнения ', font='Tahoma 20', command=equation)
labela = Label(root, text='a', font='Tahoma 16')
labelb = Label(root, text='b', font='Tahoma 16')
labelc = Label(root, text='c', font='Tahoma 16')

label_main.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.01, anchor='n')
a.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor='n')
b.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor='n')
c.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor='n')
labela.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.09, anchor='n')
labelb.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.19, anchor='n')
labelc.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.29, anchor='n')
but.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='n')
root.mainloop()
```

---

Черт, акелла промахнулся. Не тот кусок кода
https://pastebin.com/1kRckN8y

Comment: `b.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor='n')` -> 
`NameError: name 'b' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За правильность вычислений не ручаюсь, но теперь по крайней мере работает:

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
def setwindow(root):
    root.title('Окно программы')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    w = 800
    h = 600
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    wh = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = int(ws / 2 - w / 2)
    y = int(wh / 2 - h / 2)
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}".format(w, h, x, y))

def equation():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global result
    x1 = float(b.get()) * -1 + sqrt(float(b.get()) ** 2 - float(a.get()) * float(c.get() * 4) / float(a.get()) * 2)
    x2 = float(b.get()) * -1 - sqrt(float(b.get()) ** 2 - float(a.get()) * float(c.get() * 4) / float(a.get()) * 2)
    result.config(text="x1 = " + str(x1) + "; " + "x2 = " + str(x2))

root = Tk()
setwindow(root)

label_main = Label(root, text='ax^2 + bx + c = 0', font='tahoma 20')
a = Entry(root, font='Tahoma 16')
b = Entry(root, font='Tahoma 16') # пропало куда-то из кода, добавил
c = Entry(root, font='Tahoma 16')
result = Label(root, font='Tahoma 18')
but = Button(root, text='Вычеслить корень уравнения ', font='Tahoma 20', command=equation)
labela = Label(root, text='a', font='Tahoma 16')
labelb = Label(root, text='b', font='Tahoma 16')
labelc = Label(root, text='c', font='Tahoma 16')

label_main.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.01, anchor='n')
a.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor='n')
b.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor='n')
c.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor='n')
labela.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.09, anchor='n')
labelb.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.19, anchor='n')
labelc.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.29, anchor='n')
but.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='n')
result.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor='n') # добавил, иначе не отображалось
root.mainloop()
```

Основная суть в том, что надо сначала преобразовывать поля в `float`, а потом уже что-то с ними делать. У вас много где было наоборот - сначала что-то делалось со значением поля, которое на самом деле строка, а потом уже преобразовывалось в число. Понятно, что взять корень от строки нельзя, например.

Comment: Ага, теперь лучше. Но код все равно не будет выполняться, есть ошибка ValueError: math domain error. Он не хочет извлекать корень, почему? Потому что он из отрицательного числа?

Comment: Ну в принципе нет проблем просто cmath.sqrt использовать. Спасибо, вы мне помогли!

Comment: @Femmefacile Если помог, отметьте ответ как правильный )

Comment: CrazyElf вы конечно вор авторитетный) и я дико извиняюсь, а где в вашем ответе разбор полётов? Почему бы не попросить автора приложить тот самый скрипт к вопросу, и предоставить полный Traceback. Ведь по существу нечего не понятно, как произошла ошибка и какое решение.

Comment: @Александр Это было 3.5 года назад, наверное один из первых моих ответов )  Но вообще я же под кодом написал в чём суть - что была попытка делать вычисления со строками, а не с числами.